# How target html and css to a specific page?

Tags: html, css, web, containers, squarespace

I am using Squarespace as my website builder. I have added a search icon above my blog feed https://www.livingwithphotography.co.uk/learn/ however for some reason the search box also appears on each blog post as well. This is what I don't want, instead I just want it to be shown on this page https://www.livingwithphotography.co.uk/learn/.

In order to code search icon I added this code in the site header

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

I then added this css code

```
.myTitle {
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid grey;
margin: 40px; 
font-size: 22px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Lastly I then added this code to the PAGE HEADER CODE INJECTION

```
<div class="myTitle"><a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b"><img src="https://livingwithphotography.squarespace.com/s/Screen-Shot-2015-06-01-at-120646.png" alt="search icon" style="width:20px">  <a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b">Search</a></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myTitle").prependTo("#content");
});
</script>
```

I hope there is a way, thanks for your help :)

Comment: So what you're saying is if you went to the blog post https://www.livingwithphotography.co.uk/learn/how-to-take-landscape-photographs for example, you don't want the search field, correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct if I click on any blog post I don't want the search icon to show.

Comment: Ok, so the only place you want the search field is on your learn page right?

Comment: yes that is correct jordon :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky, but it should work. Wrap the code where you prepend the div in this if.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.pathname == "/learn") {
        $(".myTitle").prependTo("#content");
    }
});
```

Comment: if(window.location.pathname == "/learn") {
    <div class="myTitle"><a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b"><img src="https://livingwithphotography.squarespace.com/s/Screen-Shot-2015-06-01-at-120646.png" alt="search icon" style="width:20px">  <a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b">Search</a></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myTitle").prependTo("#content");
});
</script>
}

Comment: @Lawrence No not quite. Don't surround everything in the if statement, just the part in the script, I'll update my answer to show you :)

Comment: @Lawrence No problem man! Be sure to mark my answer as correct if this worked for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not correct instead the icon has moved to the top of the screen     <div class="myTitle"><a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b"><img src="https://livingwithphotography.squarespace.com/s/Screen-Shot-2015-06-01-at-120646.png" alt="search icon" style="width:20px">  <a href="/search?q=&f_collectionId=5568d109e4b0cb923356090b">Search</a></div>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.pathname == "/learn") {
        $(".myTitle").prependTo("#content");
    }
});</script>

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Is everything working other than the positioning of the search bar? And did you change any other code other than wrapping the prepend in the if?

Comment: every thing is working and the only code that i have changed is this thats all   <script>$(document).ready(function() { if(window.location.pathname == "/learn") { $(".myTitle").prependTo("#content"); } });</script>

Comment: @Lawrence Was the search bar positioned correctly before the if statement was added?

Comment: yes it was i have just changed it the original code on my website

Comment: @Lawrence I was just looking at your site and it seems to be working, you figure it out?

Comment: No sorry i just put it back to the original code but the search icon is still appearing on other blog posts

Answer (score 0):

Lawrence,

In your CMS (SQ), the type of mod you're wanting here is actually best done in 'developer' mode. Essentially, there's only one collection-ID assigned to the blog itself, which is why when you inject to the main page/content area, it appears across the board as you've noticed. The only differentiating factor is that blog overview pages have added class of "blog-list", while blog entries pages have added class "blog-items" (again, both still contained within the same collection).

So that all said, if you're trying to do this with Jquery in an existing template on a blog module specifically (and you are **not** toggling into developer), one way to workaround is to target the first instance of the ".entry-header" class on the blog [*instead of* using 'prependTo' #content].

After targeting the first instance of the entry-header, you would additionally need to also hide the display on the '.blog-items' pages as well (these are the actual entry items themselves). With this approach, your new class "myTitle" should appear *only* on the blog overview page (in your case: /learn/), but keep it hidden on actual article entry view.

So instead of what you have now, try instead using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.myTitle').insertBefore('.entry-header:first');
});
```

Then in Custom CSS put:

```
.myTitle {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 201px;
}
.blog-item .myTitle {
    display: none;
}
```

As a note, while it's not totally "proper" form, many just put the whole shebang right into the blog module header since it's page specific and won't run globally.

In that case, you would just input all your code directly into: > Configure Blog > Advanced. Here's a screenshot example (note: *shot taken directly from their UI and why the line wraps look funky*):

[image]

Last note: This method does work, however, bear in mind that if you've manipulated other elements in your site as well (which I wouldn't know if you did) then those other changes could also impact.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Squarespace search block and summary block to do this without any coding:

1. Just create a new page.
2. Insert a "search" block and constrain it to only search your blog collection.
   [image]
3. Insert a "summary" block and set it to display your existing blog.
   [image]

Here is an example I set up on my site to demonstrate: http://www.figjamit.com.au/example